# Two Boxplots for one X position using gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot, boxplot

I have 2 sets of data A and B, each with a y value for x=100, 200, 300. I want to create one graph which shows the difference between these two data sets. As such this means that for each x, there will be two boxplots(one for data A and one for data B).

for example, this is how the columns are organized in my data. 
DataSet A

```
#  x=100 200 300 
  1    2   3    
 1.1  2.1  3.1
 1.2  2.2  3.2
 1    2   3    
 1.01 2.01 3.01
```

DataSet B

```
#  x=100 200 300 
  6    7   9    
 6.1  7.1  9.1
 6.2  7.2  9.2
 6    7    9    
 6.01 7.01 9.01
```

I was able to get two graphs out of this data using:

```
set style fill solid 0.25 border -1
set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7
set style data boxplot
set xtics ('100' 1, '200' 2, '300' 3)
plot for [i=1:3] "A.txt" using (i):i notitle
plot for [i=1:3] "B.txt" using (i):i notitle
```

However, I am facing issues when combining it into one.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have them stacked above each other (in case they don't overlap), then you can just combine the two plot into one with

```
plot for [i=1:3] "A.txt" using (i):i notitle,\
     for [i=1:3] "B.txt" using (i):i notitle
```

If they can overlap, you may want to put them side-by-side with

```
set boxwidth 0.3
plot for [i=1:3] "A.txt" using (i-0.15):i notitle,\
     for [i=1:3] "B.txt" using (i+0.15):i notitle
```

Just to give two example of how you could combine those plots.

Comment: Thanks for that. The mistake I was making was not using specifying the for loop twice.